# Wasserstein Metric Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, optimal-transport, wasserstein

**This is the exercise:**

This exercise shows that “spreading out” probability measures makes them closer together. Define the convolution of a measure by: for any probability density function $\phi$, let $\phi*\mu$ be the measure such that, for any Borel set $A$

$$
(\phi*\mu)[A]=\int\int\mathbb{I}_A(x)\phi(x-z)d\mu(z)dx.
$$

- i) To gain intuition, take $\delta_0$ as a measure (very not spread out!), and compute $\phi*\delta_0$ for any probability density function $\phi$. Intuitively, is this “more spread out” than $\delta_0$?
- ii) Fix any compactly supported probability density function $\phi$. Show that for all $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{P}_p\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$,

$$
\mathcal{W}_p(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu)\le \mathcal{W}_p(\mu,\nu)
$$

**This is what I have done so far:**

**i)**

Let $\phi$ be a probability density function and $\delta_0$ be Dirac's Delta distribution centered at $0$, thus by definition and considering Dirac's Delta distribution's properties we have that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\phi*\delta_0)[A]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{I}_A(x)\phi(x-z)d\delta_0(z)dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{I}_A(x)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(x-z)d\delta_0(z)\right)dx.
\end{aligned}
$$

For any fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ let's define $\Phi(z):=\phi(x-z)\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so that

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\phi*\delta_0)[A]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{I}_A(x)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(x-z)d\delta_0(z)\right)dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{I}_A(x)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Phi(z)d\delta_0(z)\right)dx\\
&=\int_A\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Phi(z)\delta_0(z)dz\right)dx,
\end{aligned}
$$

such that

$$
\delta_0(z)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }z\ne 0\\\infty&\text{ if }z= 0\end{cases}.
$$

Therefore

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\phi*\delta_0)[A]&=\int_A\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Phi(z)\delta_0(z)dz\right)dx\\
&=\int_A\Phi(0)dx=\int_A\phi(x)dx.
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, notice that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$, the measure of set $A$ with respect to $\delta_0$ is given by

$$
\delta_0[A]=\int_Ad\delta_0(x)=\int_A\delta_0(x)dx=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }0\in A\\0&\text{ if }0\notin A\end{cases},
$$

compare that to the measure of set $A$ with respect to $\phi*\delta_0$

$$
(\phi*\delta_0)(A)=\int_A\phi(x)dx\in[0,1],
$$

clearly, $\delta_0$ is the unit mass concentrated at $0$. On the other hand, given the fact that $\phi$ is a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function we can conclude that $(\phi*\delta_0)$ is not necessarily concentrated at $x_0$ (unless of course $\phi\equiv\delta_{x_0}$) for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, that is $(\phi*\delta_0)$ is "more spread out" than $\delta_0$.

**ii)**

Let $\phi$ be a compactly supported probability density function and $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{P}_p\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$, then by definition we have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{W}_p(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu)&=\inf\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\|x-y\|^pd\pi'(x,y):\pi'\in\Pi(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu)\right\},\\
\mathcal{W}_p(\mu,\nu)&=\inf\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\|x-y\|^pd\pi(x,y):\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)\right\}. 
\end{aligned}
$$

And for $\rho(x,y)=h(x-y)=\|x-y\|^p$ we have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{W}_p(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu)&=C^k_{\rho}(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu),\\
\mathcal{W}_p(\mu,\nu)&=C^k_{\rho}(\mu,\nu). 
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\phi$ is compactly supported, there exists a bounded, compact set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ and $B<\infty$ such that

$$
\int_{C}\phi(y)dy=1,\text{  }\phi(x)=0\text{ for all }x\in C^c,\phi(x)\in[0,B]\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}^d,
$$

and by definition for any Borel set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\phi*\mu)[A]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{I}_A(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(x-z)d\mu(z)dx\\&=\int_A\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(x-z)d\mu(z)dx\\
&=\int_A\int_{\left\{z\in\mathbb{R}^d:x-z\in C\right\}}\phi(x-z)d\mu(z)dx\\
&=\int_A\int_{-C+x}\phi(-z+x)d\mu(z)dx,
\end{aligned}
$$

such that for a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ the set $-C+x$ is given by

$$
-C+x=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^d:z=-c+x\text{ for some }c\in C\}
$$

**Any ideas of what can I do in order to prove that:**

$$
\mathcal{W}_p(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu)\le \mathcal{W}_p(\mu,\nu)
$$

**?**

Comment: See here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044979/convolution-is-a-lipschitz-map

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{W}_p(\mu,\nu) = \left(\inf_\pi \int c(x,y)^p d\pi(x,y)\right)^{1/p}$

Where the infimum is over all couplings $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Now let $\pi'$ be any coupling of $\phi*\mu$ and $\phi*\nu$. We can construct a coupling $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$ as:

$\pi(A \times B) = \pi'(\phi(A) \times \phi(B))$

for any measurable sets $A, B$.

Then for any coupling $\pi'$ of $\phi*\mu$ and $\phi*\nu$, $\pi$ defined above is a valid coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Since $\phi$ is a convolution, we have:

$c(\phi(x),\phi(y)) \leq c(x,y)$

for the ground cost $c$.

Therefore:

$\int c(\phi(x),\phi(y))^p d\pi'(x,y) \leq \int c(x,y)^p d\pi(x,y)$

Taking the infimum over all $\pi'$ and $\pi$, this gives:

$\mathcal{W}_p(\phi*\mu,\phi*\nu) \leq \mathcal{W}_p(\mu,\nu)$

Thus proving the inequality.

Comment: I don't think it's true that (i) $\pi'(\phi(A)\times\phi(B))$ is necessarily a coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$ and (ii) that $c(\phi(x),\phi(y))\leq c(x,y)$. Can you please elaborate why you think these claims are true?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a beautiful proof of the advertised conclusion in Lemma 5.2 (pp 180) of the monograph [Optimal transport for applied mathematicians](http://ndl.ethernet.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/53568/1/Filippo%20Santambrogio.pdf) written by Filippo Santambrogio